# How to add a function to all scopes..

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a function on `rootScope` that I defined.

I later use it in controllers on the controller's scope - as it inherits the function from the rootScope.

now, I would like to do the same in directives with isolatedScopes. 
since they don't prototypically inherit from rootScope, I need to find a another way to place that function on each isolated scope.

is there a way to customize isolated scope on creation, or some other hook?

### update

Clarification: i need the function on the scope - not rootScope.

the reason is that we use this.$on('$destroy'...). so we basically want to execute code each time my scope is destroyed.

Current implementation: currently i override `$rootScope.$new` and check, if isolated i simply add the function on the scope. however this feels hackish and i would like to find a better solution.

here is my current code

```
    $rootScope.registerTask =  function(){

        .... 

        this.$on("$destroy", function() {
            ...
        });
    };

    $rootScope.origNew = $rootScope.$new;

    $rootScope.$new = function(isolate, parent ){

        var newScope = this.origNew(isolate, parent );

        if ( isolate ){
            newScope.unregisterTask = ...;
            newScope.registerTask = $rootScope.registerTask;
        }
        return newScope;

    };

    $rootScope.unregisterTask = ...;
```

Comment: Put that function in a service, and inject the service in all the controllers and directives that need it. You could also inject the $rootScope in your directive, but that is not as clean as using a dedicated service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh.. the answer has been in front of me all along.. because the question was wrong!

All I wanted to do is assign functions on each and every scope (including isolated).

Well, scopes have prototypical inheritance, then just use that!

```
var Scope = Object.getPrototypeOf($rootScope);
Scope.registerTask =  function(){

    .... 

    this.$on("$destroy", function() {
        ...
    });
};
Scope.unregisterTask = ...;
```

should do the charm.. anywhere on load..

just goes to show - don't write code under pressure, you will work harder and get crappy results.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can inject the `$rootScope` in to the directive as,

```
 app.directive('testDirective', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
     return {
         scope : {},
         link : function() {

         },
         controller : ['$scope', function($scope) {
             $rootScope.rootScopeFunc();
         }]
     }         
 }]);
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJPaIXGzDn8Udh0TywNa?p=preview)